# Is it possible to have different solutions for isomorphic graphs?

Tags: graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

According to the following graphs below, they are isomorphic. The matching pairs of the isomorphic graphs below are:

a - 7

b - 3

c - 5

d - 4

e - 1

f - 2

g - 6

However, I have the following:

**a - 4**

b - 3

c - 5

**d - 7**

e - 1

f - 2

g - 6

Unless I made a mistake. Thank you.
[image]

Also, is it possible to use compare adjacent matrices of each graph to see if Isomorphism exists (To be able to check in a faster rate rather than use trial and error)? Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this happens. Your solution is correct. There can generally be more than one isomorphism between different graphs, just as there can be more than one bijection between two sets, or isomorphism between two groups, or homeomorphism between two topological spaces.

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to use compare adjacent matrices of each graph to see if Isomorphism exists?

Comment: Yes. The adjacency matrix of graphs contains complete information about the graph, and if you have two graphs with adjacency matrices $A$ and $B$, they are isomorphic iff a permutation matrix $P$ exists with $P^{−1}AP=B$. Unfortunately it is not known even whether it is possible to check in polynomial time whether an isomorphism (equivalently such a permutation matrix) exists. By the way, the problem is in NP, yet it is also not known whether it is NP-complete.

Comment: Yes you are correct. I actually had to look that up because my math level is still novice. That is unfortunate; so in conclusion, would you say proving isomorphism of graphs rely mainly on guess and check? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In general: yes, this can happen. The question is, did it happen here?

You have found an isomorphism between the first graph and the second graph, but with different labels. Remembering that isomorphism is an equivalence relation, the question is: is there an isomorphism between the second graph and the second graph with different labels that turns your differently-labelled version into the correct version?